Displaying a tooltip on all admin pages
I want to be able to display a message on all admin pages of my clients. For this purpose, I'm using a plugin that sends the message. However, it is only displayed on the dashboard. I'm looking for how to display it on all tabs.
add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'add_custom_dashboard_widget' );

I tested different hooks to display on all pages, but it only shows on the dashboard

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_notices/
